# How to get the Referral URL using Google Analytics _UTM Cookies

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, referrals

I have been trying to get the exact referral URL.

I can only able to see the search term and the source in yahoo and only the source but not the search term in google. I needed the URL, How to get the URL And also if possible how to get the search term in case of google search.

Answer (score 0):

Search Term or Key word is not something that you can reliably get from Google anymore.

> Google Analytics identifies the terms that visitors used to find your
>   site through search engines, and displays these keywords (including
>   phrases) in your reports. For Google organic searches, Google
>   Analytics will generally show a a keyword of (not provided) because
>   all Google searches are secured via SSL, and search queries are not
>   exposed.

[Search term exclusions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795833?hl=en)

Note: you can see a bit more from [WebMaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/%E2%80%8E)  Search Traffic -> Search Queries